# Sitecore 9.3 Visual Studio setup help - errors on deploy

Tags: visual-studio, training-certification

I've started trying to follow the Sitecore Platform Essentials for Developer eLearning which is going fine, but when I deploy the project, the site just breaks on start with an error about no paramaterless constructor found.  I believe it's because it's copying over DLLs from my solution that are different from the dlls in the installation.

Are there any detailed guides on setting up Visual Studio with a Sitecore 9.3 installation?  I can't seem to find any documentation at all.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have set the dlls in visual studio as "copy local to false" in their properties to avoid errors as given in the following official Sitecore documentation :

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/set-up-sitecore-and-visual-studio-for-development.html

Also, make sure your controller is having a parameterless constructor like below

```
public MyController()
{
   //stuff
}
```

**EDIT :**
(Tip)
If incase your site crashes - you dont have any solution/fixes and you don't have backup, you can still find the entire folders and files of a vanilla Sitecore instance inside the installation zip file (Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip/Content/Website). You need not install a new Sitecore instance again.. :)

Specifically, set the copy local to false for System.Web.Mvc.dll besides the regular dlls such as Sitecore.Kernel, Sitecore.Mvc, Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics

Basically, if it is a dll version mismatch after deploy/publish to your webroot folder, then you would get error message such as

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc'...
```

Comment: Thanks a load!  I figured this out myself a couple of hours ago and I've been working my way through it.  Finally got to the point of a controller/etc and deploying everything, and it's still all fine.  What a relief.  Also, what a pain.  There are A LOT of sitecore dlls to set to not deploy...